# Controlling Positioning Of Footnotes In InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, page-layout

Is there any way to control the positioning of footnotes in Indesign beyond the most basic options in the footnotes dialogue?

It seems that the only option is to have them added as part of the text frame where they are referenced, meaning the text within the text frame is reduced in height to accommodate them. I would like the main text on each page to be exactly the same height, with any footnotes appearing below it, not as part of the column. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: And what do you do when you reach a footnote that’s too long to fit on the page outside the text frame? There’s a reason footnotes normally eat into the copy area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the built-in footnote feature (unless things have changed in CC, which I don't have) you're probably better off creating your own text frame and writing your footnotes manually.

You could create a solution based on [cross-references](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/cross-references.html), but that will probably be a fair amount of work to set up. If you don't have that many footnotes it's probably easier to set up and manage them manually.

There is [a script](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/foot_to_end_dynamic.jsx) that converts your footnotes to endnotes using cross-references. The script places your footnotes at the end of your text (i.e. endnotes) but you could manually move them later or possibly modify the script to place them in a new text frame on the correct page.

You can find the script here:

- http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/foot_to_endnote.html

There is a detailed explination of adding new notes and deleting existing notes after using the script here:

- http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/foot_add_delete.html

Answer (score -2):

Peter Kahrel explains exactly that in a post here, you don't need to write manually the footnotes, you need to download and install the script. I have tried and it works.

http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/sidenotes.html

Comment: this was already mentioned in the other answer